# Rudder Pedals generates no input

Tags: usb, joystick

I have a, in my opinion, strange problem. I am using the Saitek rudder pedals already a long time and they worked as it could be expected. Since some weeks I had to re-plug the pedals to get them working properly, not everytime but sometimes. But now they stopped working completely.

The strange part is that they are recognised by the system as dmesg shows:

```
dxxx@dxxxxx:/etc/udev/rules.d$ dmesg -t | tail -n7
usb 3-4.1.3: new full-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-4.1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=06a3, idProduct=0763
usb 3-4.1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 3-4.1.3: Product: Saitek Pro Flight Rudder Pedals
usb 3-4.1.3: Manufacturer: Saitek
input: Saitek Saitek Pro Flight Rudder Pedals as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.1/3-4.1.3/3-4.1.3:1.0/0003:06A3:0763.001D/input/input35
hid-generic 0003:06A3:0763.001D: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Joystick [Saitek Saitek Pro Flight Rudder Pedals] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.1.3/input0
```

Even though they show up in evtest but any input is not recognised:

```
dxxx@dxxxxx:/etc/udev/rules.d$ evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Not running as root, no devices may be available.
Available devices:
/dev/input/event13: Saitek Saitek Pro Flight Rudder Pedals
/dev/input/event16: ROCCAT ROCCAT Kone XTD
/dev/input/event17: ROCCAT ROCCAT Kone XTD
/dev/input/event18: Thrustmaster T.16000M
/dev/input/event19: Saitek Saitek Pro Flight Yoke
Select the device event number [0-19]: 13
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x6a3 product 0x763 version 0x111
Input device name: "Saitek Saitek Pro Flight Rudder Pedals"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      127
      Flat       7
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      127
      Flat       7
    Event code 5 (ABS_RZ)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      511
      Fuzz       1
      Flat      31
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
```

The rest of my input devices work properly (Saitek Pro Yoke, Thrustmaster Joystick).

I do not think that it has to do with the input device permissions as they have not been changed and look correct to me:

```
dxxx@dxxxxx:/etc/udev/rules.d$ ll /dev/input/event*
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 64 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event0
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 65 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event1
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 74 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event10
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 75 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event11
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 76 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event12
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root input  13, 77 Mär  9 20:52 /dev/input/event13
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 78 Mär  9 19:55 /dev/input/event14
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 79 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event15
crw-rw----  1 root roccat 13, 80 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event16
crw-rw----  1 root roccat 13, 81 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event17
crw-rw----+ 1 root input  13, 82 Mär  9 20:37 /dev/input/event18
crw-rw----+ 1 root input  13, 83 Mär  9 20:38 /dev/input/event19
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 66 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event2
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 67 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event3
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 68 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event4
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 69 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event5
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 70 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event6
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 71 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event7
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 72 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event8
crw-rw----  1 root input  13, 73 Mär  9 19:54 /dev/input/event9
dxxx@dxxxxx:/etc/udev/rules.d$ cat saitek-devices.rules 
# Saitek Pro Flight Rudder Pedals
# KERNEL=="js*", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0763", ATTRS{idVendor}=="06a3", MODE="0664"
KERNEL=="event*", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0763", ATTRS{idVendor}=="06a3", MODE="0666"
```

I tested the pedals at my Windows 7 laptop and they worked. Therefore they are not broken in my opinion. I also tried allmost all possible USB ports on my computer with no luck. Now I have no idea any more what the cause of this problem could be. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (4.4.0-116-generic) and apart from that X-Plane 11 does work flawlessly.

Has anyone a hint what the problem could be?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with my Saitek Pedals (Yoke works fine) running Flightgear on Ubuntu 16.04. I have no consistently good solution. The problem can sometimes be fixed by plugging and unplugging the USB, rebooting the machine usually with a period of complete power off for about 10-20 sec. Once fixed the pedals work until the machine is switched off or goes into suspend mode..... then we start again. Very annoying. I don't know enough about Linux to know how to reinitialise the USB devices except by rebooting. My system responses to demesg and evtest are almost identical to yours. C